# How do I parse a date from RFC2822 allowing a time zone at the end of the string?

Tags: rust, rfc2822, rust-chrono

I am trying to parse mail headers. I am trying to parse the date with Chrono, by giving it the [RFC2822 strings](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.3). The problem is that it is not able to parse strings on the format `2 Nov 2021 14:26:12 +0000 (UTC)`, where the problem seems to be the last part  `(UTC)`. How can I make Chrono parse also these strings?

```
use chrono::prelude::DateTime; // 0.4.19
use regex::Regex;              // 1.6.0

let date = "2 Nov 2021 14:26:12 +0000"; // does work
let date = "2 Nov 2021 14:26:12 +0000 (UTC)"; // does not work

// regex parses "[+-]dddd (www)" => " "[+-]dddd"
let re = Regex::new(r"([+-]?\d{4}) \(\w+\)$").unwrap();
let date = DateTime::parse_from_rfc2822(
        &re.replace(date_rfc2822_str, "$1")
    )
    .unwrap()
);
```

I can use regex to just remove the last part, but is it possible to parse it without this "hack"?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If yes, can we see your code?

Comment: I added a code example

Comment: Does `2 Nov 2021 14:26:12 +0000 (UTC)` match any standard? Or is it simply `RFC2822` with additional stuff attached?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if the above date string is the standard.  From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.3, I think the last line in the section (about the zone) says that this is valid inside the standard as well, but I am not sure. I have just parsed it directly from the MIME header returned from https://github.com/jonhoo/rust-imap

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is valid RFC2822. The standard specifies `CFWS` at the end, which is `*([FWS] comment) (([FWS] comment) / FWS)` and matches `(UTC)`.  `comment` is `"(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")"`. I think this is a bug in  `chrono` and should be fixed.

Comment: Was already discussed: https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/462 I'm unsure as to why they came to the conclusion though, in my opinion it's valid

Comment: Official quote from [their code](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/051e1170c41477ce162301c8711110a4577c1a23/src/format/parse.rs#L80): *we do not recognize a folding white space (FWS) or comment (CFWS). for our purposes, instead, we accept any sequence of Unicode white space characters (denoted here to `S`). any actual RFC 2822 parser is expected to parse FWS and/or CFWS themselves and replace it with a single SP (`%x20`); this is legitimate.*

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/732

Comment: Can you parse the format youself? https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.7/chrono/format/fn.parse.html

Comment: You have to strip out comments and other chaff before you parse it with the `DateTime` library. It's not aware of the full nuances of comments, which can be nested, or other quirks of the RFC5322 syntax. Maybe strip it off with a loose regular expression that just snips `\(.*`?

Comment: @tadman Might be [compatible soon](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/pull/733).

Comment: @fevar It will work as soon as I get it through the reviews. It was recognized and accepted by the devs that this is incorrect behaviour and that we need to implement compatibility with rfc2822 comments. Until it is merged, you could use this in your `Cargo.toml`: `chrono = { git = "https://github.com/Finomnis/chrono.git", branch = "rfc2822_comments" }`

Comment: @fevar: It got fixed and merged. Will be released soon. That means, though, that my branch doesn't exist anymore and the `Cargo.toml` entry of the previous message will no longer work.

Comment: @fevar: It got fixed and merged. Will be released soon. That means, though, that my branch doesn't exist anymore and the `Cargo.toml` entry of the previous message will no longer work. In the meantime, use `chrono = { git = "https://github.com/chronotope/chrono.git" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [was a bug in `chrono`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/732).

It [got fixed](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/pull/733) and will potentially be released in chrono version `0.4.20`.

```
use chrono::prelude::DateTime; // main branch

fn main() {
    let date = "2 Nov 2021 14:26:12 +0000 (UTC)";
    println!("{}", DateTime::parse_from_rfc2822(date).unwrap());
}
```

```
2021-11-02 14:26:12 +00:00
```